# エディタ拡張で生成したオブジェクトの保存

Tags: unity3d

エディタ拡張で、カスタムWindowを使って表示したボタンから、
Gameobjectを生成したり、オブジェクトの設定値を変更するスクリプトを書いています。

GameObjectを生成した後、シーンを保存しても、生成したオブジェクトや
スクリプトから変更した値が保存されません。

生成後、シーンビューからなんらかのGameobjectを移動するなど、データを一部でも変更すれば、すべての変更が保存されます。
予想するに、エディタスクリプトからGameObjectを生成したり変更したりしても、
UnityEditorには変更マークがつかず、save sceneをしても保存処理がされないのでは、
と感じました、

save sceneを押して保存されるように、変更済みマークをスクリプトから実施する方法はないでしょうか？
一通り探してみたのですが、既出でしたら申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 1):

先日Unityのフォーラムでも同様の投稿があり、Unityの中の人が解決方法を示していました。

[Custom Editor problem in Unity 5.3 | Unity Community](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/custom-editor-problem-in-unity-5-3.372970/)

一つはUndo.RecordObject()を呼び出す方法、もう一つはSerializedObjectやSerializedPropertyを使う方法です。

上記リンク先のコメントからしますと、Unityの中の人的にはSerializedObjectやSerializedPropertyを使う方法を勧めているように読めました。

以下実装例です:

[Unity-Technologies / UI / ソース / UnityEditor.UI / UI / ButtonEditor.cs — Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/b411f84ded13340515b6a48f1bfd2ea59d5348b8/UnityEditor.UI/UI/ButtonEditor.cs?at=5.3&fileviewer=file-view-default)

UnityのUI.Buttonのエディタ拡張の実装です。短いながらも簡潔に書かれていてわかりやすいです。

[Inspector を SerializedProperty を活用して拡張 - 強火で進め](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/nakamura001/20120609/1339249045)

日本語の情報としてこちらも挙げます。